# Spark settings not taking effect in YARN

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I have set

```
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions to –XX:+UseG1GC
spark.storage.memoryFraction    to 0.3
```

I can see them in the environments page. But in executors page Storage Memory still is allocating the default amount. And I do not see that Java option being used when launching the executors. I set these environments within my application using  SparkConf.set()

```
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("spark.kryoserializer.buffer", "24m");
    params.put("spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max", "1g");
    params.put("spark.kryo.registrationRequired", "true");
    params.put("spark.speculation", "false");
    params.put("spark.rdd.compress", "true");
    params.put("spark.storage.memoryFraction","0.3");
    params.put("spark.executor.extraJavaOptions","–XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+G1SummarizeConcMark -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=400 -XX:ConcGCThread=20");


    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Test");

    Arrays.asList(
            getSparkParams(),
            ElasticSearchProvider.getSparkParams()
    ).stream()
            .map(settings -> settings.entrySet().stream()
                    .map(entry -> sparkConf.set(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
                    .count())
            .count();
```

Comment: How do you start your application in YARN? `spark-submit`? What are the lines with `SparkConf.set` and `SparkContext`? Please paste them all to your question. What Spark version do you use? Thanks!